# How create home page responsive with bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to create a layout responsive like the pic down, with bootstrap 4 or other support. (full screen)

[image]

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <link href="~/Content/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="flex-row">
            <div class="col" style="background-color: blue;">Header</div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-row">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: orange;">Left Nav</div>
            <div class="col" style="background-color: gray;">Content</div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-row" style="background-color: green;">
            Footer
        </div>

    </div>

    @RenderBody()

</body>

</html>

.container 
{   height: 100%;
    width: 100%; }
```

Any idea for this ?

p.s. I work with VS2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created your design using bootstrap col.You can modify the height as you wish but you can use this layout for your blueprint.For more info you can check : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Control the column width, and how they should appear on different devices -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;height:200px">Header</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row" style="height:450px">
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">Left Navigation</div>
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:orange;">Content</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!-- Or let Bootstrap automatically handle the layout -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;height:225px">Footer</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I saw yours thats fine but why don't you use material-grid list?Thats better solution and you don't need to add anything here you can see how it works on this sample project https://codepen.io/tokumewi/pen/bdMewG

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="col" style="background-color: #5B9BD5;">Header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #ED7D31;">Left Nav</div>
        <div class="col" style="background-color: #A5A5A5;">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row" style="background-color: #70AD47;">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but your solution isn't full screen !